# Jersey & Spring managed providers

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm using **Jersey 2.4.1**, **Spring 3.2.4** and **Jetty 7**.

I don't understand how Jersey registers providers that are managed by Spring.
My classes annotated with `@Provider` are also annotated `@Component` because I need injection.
I configured Jersey to scan my packages with these providers.

Here is how I configure Jersey servlet:

```
public void createJerseyServlet() {
  ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
  resourceConfig.packages("test.web", "org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring");
  resourceConfig.register(LoggingFilter.class);
  ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
  servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
}
```

The logs at startup:

```
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider - Spring context lookup done.
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider - Spring component provider initialized.
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider - Spring managed bean, testResource, registered with HK2.
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider - Spring managed bean, nullPointerExceptionMapper, registered with HK2.
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider - Spring managed bean, filterTest, registered with HK2.
[...]
INFO - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler - Jersey application initialized.
Root Resource Classes:
  org.obiba.jta.web.TestResource
Pre-match Filters:
   org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter
Global Response Filters:
   org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter
Global Reader Interceptors:
   org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor
Global Writer Interceptors:
   org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter
[...]
```

My providers are detected via Spring: `Spring managed bean, filterTest, registered with HK2` but they don't appear in the `ApplicationHandler` logs...
And they are not used when I run the application.

I need to manually register them:

```
@Resource
private FilterTest filterTest;

@Resource
private MyExceptionMapper myExceptionMapper;

[...]

resourceConfig.register(filterTest);
resourceConfig.register(myExceptionMapper);
```

Or even better... for a workaround :(

```
Map<String, Object> providers = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Provider.class);
for(Object provider : providers.values()) {
  resourceConfig.register(provider);
}
```

Now it works (even if they still don't appear in `ApplicationHandler` logs) but I don't understand why Jersey does not register them automatically when it scans the package and see that these bean are managed by Spring...

---

Here are my components...

#### Resource

```
package test.web;

@Transactional
@Component
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
  @Resource
  private MyService myService;

  @GET
  @Path("/inject")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String testInjection() {
    return "integrationService: " + integrationService;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/active")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String testActiveTransaction() {
    return "isActualTransactionActive: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/exception")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String testException() {
    throw new MyException();
  }
}
```

#### Filter

```
package test.web.cfg;

@Provider
@Component
public class FilterTest implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Resource
  private MyService myService;
  [...]
}
```

#### ExceptionMapper

```
package test.web.cfg;

@Provider
@Component
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("MyException was thrown!").build();
  }
}
```

#### And finally my dependencies

```
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.4.1")
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.4.1")
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.4.1")
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.4.1")
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:2.4.1")
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:2.4.1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug...

Package scanning component registry not working: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2175